# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types at cpvlap stats

Tags: javascript, java, c#, arrays, performance

I found this error in the error stats file

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home1/bestdail/public_html/cpvlap/cpv_lab_install_files/stats.php on line 338
```

and here's the row 338

```
$totalsRow[0] += $columnsForTotals[$j] = $reportLines[$i][$columnsForTotals[$j]];
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

In this line you mentioned you have to assignments which is not correct:

```
$totalsRow[0] += $columnsForTotals[$j] = $reportLines[$i][$columnsForTotals[$j]];
```

As you will notice you are saying this:

```
 $totalsRow[0] = $totalsRow[0] + $columnsForTotals[$j] = $reportLines[$i][$columnsForTotals[$j]];
```

Which is what is throwing your error, so you need to find out what exactly you want to do in this line and have one only assignment. So fix that line and you should be ok I think. Also remember since we don't know what those variables are, make sure that `$columnsForTotals[$j]]` return an int since you are using it as an index for an array.